# How do I reattach and close multiple screen sessions from a list

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

I am an Ubuntu 9.04 user.  Given a list of screen sessions such as the following:

```
9076.pts-30.moe (09/27/2009 11:30:08 PM)    (Attached)
8778.pts-24.moe (09/27/2009 11:29:46 PM)    (Detached)
8674.pts-0.moe  (09/27/2009 11:29:25 PM)    (Attached)
22649.pts-28.moe    (09/27/2009 11:51:46 AM)    (Detached)
22543.pts-24.moe    (09/27/2009 11:50:56 AM)    (Detached)
22228.pts-16.moe    (09/27/2009 11:49:59 AM)    (Detached)
```

How would I close out multiple screens based on a time criterion?  For instance, all screens initiated before 12:00 PM.  I normally would type:

```
    screen -dr 22649.pts-28.moe
    exit
    ...
```

and close each one out manually, but this is tedious.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send commands to a screen using the -X parameter. So you can close a screen from the command line by saying "screen -S 22649.pts-28.moe -X quit".

To select the screens by time, I guess you have to run a script to compare the times.

Personally, I would use os.popen() and time.strptime() in python.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I kill all detached screens:

```
screen -ls | grep Detached | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} screen -X -S {} kill
```

if you want to forcibly kill all screens, just change `grep Detached` above to `grep tached`. Works for me all the tine, at the very least!

for time criterion, you can start with this:

```
screen -ls | grep Detached | awk -F " " '{print $2,$3,$4","$1}'
```

this prints something like:

```
(01/03/2012 02:10:42 AM),4504.test2
(01/03/2012 02:10:12 AM),4445.test1
(01/03/2012 02:02:58 AM),4333.test0
```

where the first group is the timestamp and separated by a comma, is the PID.name.

so you could use/pipe to `awk` (or `awk -F"," '{print $1}'` to exactly extract the timestamps only, in parentheses) again to parse the time inside the parentheses.. remember, `screen -ls` always lists the earliest screen last!

I have not figured out how to do time criterion filtering myself, i'll edit this in the future if i could.. good luck buddy!

Answer (score 1):

The number before the dot (`22649` in your example) is the PID of the screen process. Just kill it (`kill 22649`)